# How to do POST request with Newman?

Tags: scala, newman

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `curl -XPOST http://example.com -d '{"query":{"term":{"user":"kimchy"}}}'`. My code looks like the following

```
// this uses dijon
val query = json"""{
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}"""

implicit val httpClient = new ApacheHttpClient

val url = new URL("http://example.com")
val result = POST(url).setBody(query.toString()).apply

result onComplete {
  case Success(response) => println(s"************* ${response.toJson().toString()}")
  case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
  case r => println(s"################################### ${r}")
}
println(result)
```

but I'm not seeing anything from the `onComplete` block. What's the right way to do POST using Newman?

Comment: Could you try to use `println(Await.result(result, Duration.Inf))` instead of using a callback and see the output?

Comment: That outputs `HttpResponse(Ok,Some(NonEmptyList((Content-Type,application/json; charset=UTF-8), (Content-Length,123))),[B@12411884,Thu Aug 21 13:36:19 PDT 2014)`.

Comment: Changing it to `println(Await.result(result, Duration.Inf).bodyString)` looks good: `{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`. Any idea why the callback isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments, my guess is that this has something to do with futures and threads rater than Newman.

I think that the main thread shuts down before the future can complete, meaning that when the future complete and the callback is executed the main thread where the results are posted is no longer responsive, using `Await` fix this issue but you have to block your application to achieve this. This may also depends on you using the `ExecutionContext` given by `scala.concurrent` where the callback is registered, and you may have to use a different one to avoid this behavour, for your case though I would stick to:

```
Await.result(result, Duration.Inf) // maybe use a non infinite duration here
```